# How to make a page break in rmarkdwn html?

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, page-break

I use this following code in r-markdown to make a page break in order to printing easier. But it shows [1]"" in the html. why? How to delete it? or how to clearly make a page break in other ways?

````html
```{r, comment=NA, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
print("<P style='page-break-before: always'>")
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Always insert a page-break after a `<div>` element:

```html
<div style="page-break-after: always;"></div>
```

2. Always insert a page-break before a `<div>` element:

```html
<div style="page-break-before: always;"></div>
```

The markdown exporter might fail sometimes. To solve such problems, try to export as HTML format, open the file on browser and print as pdf(if required).